# A system of quadratic simultaneous equations admits no solution in positive integers.

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, systems-of-equations, nonlinear-system

The question and its answer is given below:

Prove the following assertion:

> [image]

The solution is given below:

> [image]

But I do not understand why if each of the given equations admits a solution the the product of them admits a solution, is there a theorem which says this? If so please can anyone mention the theorem for me?

Comment: If $(x,y)$ satisfies the two equations then it satisfies the product equation.

Comment: Is it a trivial question like this? so it is by common sense @lulu?

Comment: @Smart Apparently, you are not surprised by the part that $x^4-y^4=z^2$ has no solution in positive integers (This is well known, but the less obvious part). If we have two equations, it is obvious that the product of the left sides is equal to the product of the right sides because we simply multiply the same numbers together.

Comment: both $x^2 + y^2 = 1$ and $x^2 + y^2 = 2$ have a solution in positive integers but together they have non @lulu

Comment: The problem specifies (for purpose of contradiction) that the two quadratics have a $\textit {simultaneous}$ solution.  That means a single $(x,y)$ works for both.

Comment: did the problem specified this?@lulu ..... I can not see where is this part.

Comment: @Smart It starts to look like common sense when you get well-versed with the properties of polynomials. But this property follows very simply if you see that any polynomial can be written as a product of monic linear factors. So, each root satisfies not only the equation found by equating the corresponding factor to zero, but also the "product" equation, i.e, the polynomial equated to zero

Comment: @Aaratrick so are you saying that this is correct in case of integral domains?

Comment: I see that the solution assumed separately that each equation has a solution and then said directly (without explaining why) that the simultaneous system has a solution @lulu

Comment: @Peter I know this from Fermat last theorem or more precisely fermat last theorem consequences.

Comment: The original statement specifies $\textit {simultaneous}$.  That's clearly essential.  There is no difficulty at all in finding solutions to the two quadratics separately.

Comment: @lulu Do you mean that any two quadratics can have solutions in the set of positive integers separately or this is special for those 2 quadratics? If it is special for those 2 quadratics, why you are sure that you can find all solutions to them separately?

Comment: @hopefully I mean that it is obvious that those two quadratics can each be solved, separately.  Just think about pythagorean triples.

Comment: @lulu and how is the line before last in the solution given above comes from the line just before it?

Comment: @hopefully  The author is abusing notation in a fairly standard way.  The meaning of "$z$" changes between those two lines.  Between the two lines, $zw$ has been renamed as $z$.  I agree this sort of thing can be confusing, but it is quite common so it's worth getting used to.

Comment: got it thanks! @lulu

Comment: @Smart I only know it the other way round. The fact that the equation has no nontrivial solutions implies the case $n=4$ of Fermat's last theorem. I am not aware of a proof starting with Fermat's last theorem and ending with "$x^4-y^4=z^2$ has no solution in positive integers".