# Use a previous problem to establish that there is no solution in positive integers of simultaneous equations.

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, systems-of-equations, nonlinear-system

Problem 4 mentioned in the question is given below:

[A system of quadratic simultaneous equations admits no solution in positive integers.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3267940/a-system-of-quadratic-simultaneous-equations-admits-no-solution-in-positive-inte)

And here is the question:

> [image]

**My questions are:**

1- How can I prove the hint?

2- How can I use the hint to solve the question?

Comment: Can you prove the second equation in the hint? It is easier than you think.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your two equations are

$$x^2 + y^2 = z^2 \tag{1}\label{eq1}$$

$$x^2 + 2y^2 = w^2 \tag{2}\label{eq2}$$

\eqref{eq2} - \eqref{eq1} gives

$$y^2 = w^2 - z^2 \; \iff \; z^2 + y^2 = w^2 \tag{3}\label{eq3}$$

Rearranging \eqref{eq1} gives

$$z^2 - y^2 = x^2 \tag{4}\label{eq4}$$

These are the equations in the hint, so this answers your first question. As you can see, \eqref{eq3} and \eqref{eq4} are the same form as the equations in [A system of quadratic simultaneous equations admits no solution in positive integers.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3267940/a-system-of-quadratic-simultaneous-equations-admits-no-solution-in-positive-inte), where the variable names used are just somewhat different. In both cases, you have the sum of two perfect squares and the difference of two perfect squares each being a perfect squares. Going from these equations to those ones, you have $z$ going to $x$, $y$ staying the same, $w$ going to $z$ and $x$ going to $w$. Making those variable name changes gives you those $2$ other equations of

$$x^2 + y^2 = z^2 \tag{5}\label{eq5}$$
$$x^2 - y^2 = w^2 \tag{6}\label{eq6}$$

As shown in that other question, there are no integral solutions to the simultaneous equations \eqref{eq5} and \eqref{eq6}. Thus, there are no solutions either to \eqref{eq1} and \eqref{eq2} (since, if there were, then the sequence of equations & variable changes given here shows there would be solutions in \eqref{eq5} and \eqref{eq6}). This answers your second question regarding how to use the hint to solve the problem.

Answer (score 1):

1) To prove the hint just substitute x²+y² by z² in the second equation. You will get z²+y²=w².

2) Adding the two equations in the hint would give 2*z²=w² which is not possible.

Comment: Use LaTeX please.

Comment: For your "2)", adding the two equations in the hint actually gives $2z^2 = w^2 + x^2$, *not* $2z^2 = w^2$ as you stated.